# How to create a polymorphic array with linq to xml?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

Is it possible to use LINQ to XML to create an array of a polymorphic type?

I have 3 classes, Base, Der1 and Der2. Base is base class for Der1 and Der2. I have an xml file in which I have nodes corresponding to Der1 and Der2 objets. What I'd like to do is to parse the file and fill in a List with Der1 and Der2 objects.

xml would look like this:

```
<nodes>
    <node type = "Der1" attr1="val1" />
    <node type = "Der2" attr2="val2" />
</nodes>
```

What I tried to do but what does not work is:

```
List<Base> PMList = 
(from der1node from xmlDoc.Descendants("nodes") 
where der1node.type == ("Der1") 
select new Der1()
{
    Attr1 = der1node.Attribute("attr1").Value
}
).Union<Base>
(from der2node from xmlDoc.Descendants("baseNode") 
where der2node.type == ("Der2") 
select new Der2()
{
    Attr2 = der2node.Attribute("attr2").Value
}
).ToList<Base>();
```

Here what I tried to do is to construct Der1 objects with type=Der1 and Der2 objects with type=Der2 and add them together into a List using Union.

However this does not work. How can I get objects of different type using LINQ to XML and put them in one polymorphic collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to cast the new instances to their base class before projecting them:

```
List<Base> PMList = (from baseNode from xmlDoc.Descendants("nodes") 
                     where baseNode.type == ("Der1") 
                     select (Base) new Der1() {
                         Attr1 = baseNode.Attribute("attr1").Value
                     }
                    ).Union(
                     from baseNode from xmlDoc.Descendants("baseNode") 
                     where baseNode.type == ("Der2") 
                     select (Base) new Der2() {
                         Attr2 = baseNode.Attribute("attr2").Value
                     }
                    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Cast the object form select to Base type:

```
(from der1node from xmlDoc.Descendants("nodes") 
where der1node.type == ("Der1") 
select new Der1()
{
    Attr1 = der1node.Attribute("attr1").Value
} as Base
)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create your sequences, just make sure you cast the projection to the base type that way it becomes an `IEnumerable<Base>` instead of `IEnumerable<Der1>`.

```
List<Base> PMList = 
    (from der1node from xmlDoc.Descendants("nodes") 
     where der1node.type == ("Der1") 
     select new Der1()
     {
         Attr1 = der1node.Attribute("attr1").Value
     } as Base).Union(
    (from der2node from xmlDoc.Descendants("baseNode") 
     where der2node.type == ("Der2") 
     select new Der2()
     {
         Attr2 = der2node.Attribute("attr2").Value
     } as Base)).ToList();
```

Alternatively you can call the `Cast<Base>()` on the sequence beforehand.

```
List<Base> PMList = 
    (from der1node from xmlDoc.Descendants("nodes") 
     where der1node.type == ("Der1") 
     select new Der1()
     {
         Attr1 = der1node.Attribute("attr1").Value
     }).Cast<Base>().Union(
    (from der2node from xmlDoc.Descendants("baseNode") 
     where der2node.type == ("Der2") 
     select new Der2()
     {
         Attr2 = der2node.Attribute("attr2").Value
     }).Cast<Base>()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

On a side note, did you consider using [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) instead of union? Union will remove duplicates, which in your current state shouldn't be issue.
However, if at some point you override equality of `Der1` and `Der2` some items might suddenly stop appearing in the list. It's good to be aware of that.

Anyways, here's how I would do it:

```
var items = xmlDoc.Descendants("nodes")
    .Where(d1 => d1.type == ("Der1"))
    .Cast<Base>()
    .Concat(xmlDoc.Descendants("nodes")
        .Where(d2 => d2.type = ("Der2"))
        .Cast<Base>()
    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this comes like 7 years later. But in case the **order of the elements** is relevant to your use case. Here I provide an alternative without using `Union` that preserves the order. The following code assumes that "nodes" is the **root element**.

```
// Explicitly specify the return value to the Base type
var nodes = xmlDoc.Root.Elements().Select<XElement, Base>((e, index) => {
    string type = (e.Attribute("type") != null)?e.Attribute("type").Value:null;
    if(type != null) {
        if(type.Equals("Der1")) {
            // If you have something like an order property, you can assign it to index
            return new Der1() { Attr1 =  e.Attribute("attr1").Value };
        }
        else if(type.Equals("Der2")) {
            return new Der2() { Attr2 =  e.Attribute("attr2").Value };
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        // You can also throw an Exception and handle it.
        return null;
    }
}).ToList();
```